# Include both deep and shallow object views in the same JSON

Tags: json, jackson

Given an enum like this:

```
public enum Planet{
    MERCURY ("Mercury", 0.4),
    VENUS ("Venus", 0.7),
    EARTH ("Earth", 1.0),
    MARS ("Mars", 1.5);

    private final String name;
    private final double distance;

    Planet(String name, double distance, double mass){
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public double getDistance(){
        return distance;
    }
}
```

...and class that has this enum as property like this:

```
public class Route{
    private Planet from;
    private Planet to;

    public Route (Planet from, Planet to){
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public Planet getFrom(){
        return from;
    }

    public Planet getTo(){
        return to;
    }
}
```

what is correct way to serialize it to JSON with Jackson so that resulting JSON contains both deep and shallow Planet enum like this:

```
{
    "planets":{
        "MERCURY":{
            "name":"Mercury",
            "distance":"0,4"
        },
        ... 
    },
    "route":{
        "from":"EARTH",
        "to":"MARS"
    }
}
```

First, to get deep enum structure I annotate it with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)`, but then it also get serialized deeply within the `route` property.

How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following solution.

1. Annotated the Planet enum as follows:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum Planet{
    /* skipped */
}
```

By default enums are serialized by Jackson as String (constant names), but with this annotation Jackson will give us deep enum structure.

2. Annotated property getters

```java
public class Route{

    /* skipped */

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)    
    public Planet getFrom(){/*...*/}

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    public Planet getTo(){/*...*/}
}
```

Here we override serializing enums as objects and ask Jackson to simply give us an enum's constant name.

3. Last, but not least, added `Map<String, Planet>` to the Planet enum:

```java
public enum Planet {

    /*skipped*/

    private static Map<String, Planet> planetsMap;

    static {
        planetMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Planet planet : Planet.values()) {
            planetMap.put(planet.name(), planet);
        }
    }

    public static Map<String,Planet> getPlanets(){
        return new HashMap<>(planetsMap);
    }
}
```

Introduction of static map within the Planet enum allows us to pass this map to Jackson JSON serializer and get `"planets"` property as shown in the JSON above, with enum constant names as keys.